# Return String formatted like a credit card number Using XAML And MVVM

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvmcross

> How to set credit card number format In xaml
>
> Like

```
 1234-1234-1234-1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by using Value converters.

```
public class CreditCardNumberValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var builder = new StringBuilder(Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", ""));

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, builder.Length / 4).Reverse())
      builder.Insert(4*i + 4, " ");

    return builder.ToString().Trim();
  }

  public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), @"\D", "");
  }
}
```

After initialising this in Styles.cs, you can apply it to the Text property of the control in XAML as:

```
Text="{Binding CardNo, Converter={StaticResource CreditCardNumberValueConverter}}"
```

Likewise, Phone numbers too can also be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label Text="{Binding YourVmPropertyNameHere StringFormat='{0:0000-0000-0000-0000}'}">
```

This is assuming that your view model has already converted the number to an integer and set it to the property "YourVmPropertyNameHere".

Comment: This is Not Working

Comment: @Happy, Try replacing the zeros (0) with hashes (#) `StringFormat='{0:####-####-####-####}'}` other wise the next best option is to use value converter